# How to change the Z order of link objects in pdfs (i.e. send back)

Tags: pdf

Adobe Acrobat and Master PDF editor both allow users to change the Z order of objects (i.e. determine which object is obscured when objects overlap). However, neither appears to allow the same functionality for link objects (A link object is created by clicking "Insert Link" in Master PDF editor). Links created more recently have the shallowest z value (at front). Some pdf readers will return the shallowest link at the user-clicked coordinates.

Is there a way to set these Z values in any program or language without deleting them all and recreating them in the exact order needed?

Comment: Relevance to Ubuntu?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu, and there's a few pdf questions on this forum. But yeah, maybe this is a stackoverflow question? Is there anywhere else I should ask this?

Answer (score 0):

The program [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) has this functionality.